# How do I make my output appear more like my text?

Tags: c++

For my homework lab I'm supposed to:

> Define a class called textLines that will be used to store a list of lines of text
>     (each line can be specified as a string or a c-string, whichever you prefer).
>     Use a dynamic array to store the list.
>     In addition, you should have a private data member that specifies the length of the list.
>    Create a constructor that takes a file name as parameter, and fills up the list with lines from the file.

There's more but those are functions and not relevant to the question.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Define class called textLines (used to store list of lines)
class textLines
{
public:
    // Main Constructor
    textLines(ifstream& myfile1){

        pointer = new string[stringsize];

        if (myfile1.fail()) {
            cout << "File failed to open.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            for (int index = 0; index < stringsize; index++) {
                myfile1 >> pointer[index];
            }
    }
    // Constructor that takes an integer parameter that sets the size of an empty list.
    textLines(int){
        pointer = new string[0];
    }
    // Deconstructor
    ~textLines(){
        delete[] pointer;
    }

    void printArray();


private:
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    static int stringsize;
    string* pointer;
};

// Begin Main Function
int main(){

    string myfile = "Lab3Text.txt";

    ifstream infile(myfile);

    textLines text(infile);
    text.printArray();


    return 0;
}
// End Main


int textLines::stringsize = 1000;

void textLines::printArray(){

    for (int index = 0; index < stringsize; index++) {
        cout << pointer[index];
    }

}
```

And this is what my text file looks like:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

My output comes out like this, however:

```
Output: HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld
```

What's a simple fix that I can make my output appear more like my text file, in rows?

Comment: Read lines with `getline(file, pointer[index]); ` and add a new line at each line output: `cout << pointer[index] << '\n';`

Comment: Thank your instructor for allowing you to use `std::string`.  We need more instructors like this.

Comment: You might also want to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator (Rule of Three). For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1025391

Answer (score 0):

Just add endl (end line) to your output.

```
void textLines::printArray(){

    for (int index = 0; index < stringsize; index++) {
        cout << pointer[index] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried, they just appear on top of each other, hello on top of world on top of hello

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code in following lines:
    file >> pointer[index];
to 
    getline(file, pointer[index];
and
    cout << pointer[index];
to 
    cout << pointer[index] << '\n';
Why? `getline()` reads one line, not just one word, `'\n'` provides a new line on output.

Please reconsider the value of `stringsize`, since you print out garbage if your file contains less lines. Much more "C++ style" would be to have a member `vector<string> lines;` with

```
string input;
while(getline(file, input) lines.push_pack(input);
```

for input and

```
for (size_type i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
  cout << lines[i] << '\n';
```

for output. Your class with naked pointers in the current form is prone to leak memory when used with assignment operator (see [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).